# Possible to ask mysql database for maxvalues per minute but if there no data for few hours give zero values per minute?

Tags: mysql, group-by, max, hour

I have a query :

```
$table = "(select x_datetime, Max(`$wert`) as `$wert` FROM `$promess2` GROUP  BY DATE(x_datetime), HOUR(x_datetime), MINUTE(x_datetime) DIV 10) as BLA";
```

That gave me data for highstock, but when some data is lost maybe a few hour this query doesn't return data for this because there is no data.

Is it possible without filling the database with zero or null data to get NULL for the minute query ?

Comment: Why do you want to store that information?

Comment: i have an chart that show mesurement data, but sometimes (if we put it to another place or something) we lost some data. Then there are two option at highcharts, dont show the lost data and you didnt see a space between the data in chart. Or you set connectnulls to false. but then you will have this : [Link](http://s1.directupload.net/images/140905/dct4tjpl.png) i just want highstock to show null data on that place

Comment: So the problem is in your chart, not in your data, correct?
Ultimately this is a presentation issue, so anything you do in SQL is just going to be a bodge. Personally I would fix the chart before I implemented a hack in SQL.

Comment: the problem is the lost data, highcharts show correctly. But i need as output NULL from Max(value) from dates where no data is

Comment: Is there a defined range for the report? The simplest solution is to generate a record per minute and outer join to this. This is only realistically possible if you can provide a start and end point for your data set.

Comment: i can get the start and the end date yes, how can i do the rest ?

Comment: You basically need to generate a list of all possible groups between the range boundaries. One way to do this is to implement a numbers table and then use this to in turn generate the date values. Once you have this you can then outer join to your existing results.

Comment: this was the answer which helped me thank you